# Можно ли как то поменять ширину трека на в UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift

Может кто подскажет можно ли изменить ширину трека.

Задача сделать вот такие ползунки для регулировки громкости
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно свой `UIControl` написать

Comment: это пока для меня проблематично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для стандартного `UISwitch` этого сделать нельзя, как и советуют в комментарии, можно сделать кастомный `UIControl`, [вот](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2297-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider) например подробнейшее руководство (на английском)

Ключевые моменты:

- наследоваться от UIControl (можно конечно и от `UIView`, но нужно будет добавлять свои обработчики событий)
- рисовать все элементы в `drawRect:`
- или добавить для элементов (если они будут, у вас кажется просто линия) слои и рисование реализовать в методе `drawInContext:` каждого слоя
- обработку событий реализовать используя методы `beginTrackingWithTouch`, `continueTrackingWithTouch`, `endTrackingWithTouch`
- по вкусу добавить обработку изменения свойств